# Exception 'EOF' got while validating JSON

Tags: json

I have JSON which is showing an error while validating. I tried to end each JSON object by giving ',' but did not work. Here is sample JSON:

```
  {
        "_type": "Log4K",
        "_id": "285b2595c3587ee0481fb9",
        "_source": {
            "severity": "informational",
            "facility": "Box",
            "user": "KellyAnne Conway",
            "object_type": "DiscoverOrg Debug Log",
            "File_Size": 999.23731515620455,
            "Object_Id": "87284ba49816993f38",
            "__source": "API",
            "object_name": 571761,
            "Activity_type": "Download",
            "location": "somewhere",
            "created_timestamp": "2017-07-19T23:22:52",
            "device": "thing",
            "message": "words",
            "inserted_timestamp": "2017-07-19T23:22:52",
            "user_name": "KellyAnneConway",
            "elastica_user": "KellyAnneConway",
            "browser": "ibrows"
        }
      }{
        "_type": "Log4K",
        "_id": "17f7a297888a20c99f061f",
        "_source": {
            "severity": "informational",
            "facility": "Box",
            "user": "KellyAnne Conway",
            "object_type": "DiscoverOrg Debug Log",
            "File_Size": 997.20972647644385,
            "Object_Id": "13efab244409d3a384",
            "__source": "API",
            "object_name": 190852,
            "Activity_type": "Download",
            "location": "somewhere",
            "created_timestamp": "2017-07-19T23:23:52",
            "device": "thing",
            "message": "words",
            "inserted_timestamp": "2017-07-19T23:23:52",
            "user_name": "KellyAnneConway",
            "elastica_user": "KellyAnneConway",
            "browser": "ibrows"
        }
     } {
        "_type": "Log4K",
        "_id": "baf2b75f2c99808380111b",
        "_source": {
            "severity": "informational",
            "facility": "Box",
            "user": "KellyAnne Conway",
            "object_type": "DiscoverOrg Debug Log",
            "File_Size": 999.6903850242071,
            "Object_Id": "94938cc74f38959add",
            "__source": "API",
            "object_name": 366190,
            "Activity_type": "Download",
            "location": "somewhere",
            "created_timestamp": "2017-07-19T23:24:52",
            "device": "thing",
            "message": "words",
            "inserted_timestamp": "2017-07-19T23:24:52",
            "user_name": "KellyAnneConway",
            "elastica_user": "KellyAnneConway",
            "browser": "ibrows"
        }
     }
```

I am getting an error of **'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'**  while validating above JSON online.

Answer (score 0):

You JSON should look like below:

```
[{
    "_type": "Log4K",
    "_id": "285b2595c3587ee0481fb9",
    "_source": {
        "severity": "informational",
        "facility": "Box",
        "user": "KellyAnne Conway",
        "object_type": "DiscoverOrg Debug Log",
        "File_Size": 999.23731515620455,
        "Object_Id": "87284ba49816993f38",
        "__source": "API",
        "object_name": 571761,
        "Activity_type": "Download",
        "location": "somewhere",
        "created_timestamp": "2017-07-19T23:22:52",
        "device": "thing",
        "message": "words",
        "inserted_timestamp": "2017-07-19T23:22:52",
        "user_name": "KellyAnneConway",
        "elastica_user": "KellyAnneConway",
        "browser": "ibrows"
    }
}, {
    "_type": "Log4K",
    "_id": "17f7a297888a20c99f061f",
    "_source": {
        "severity": "informational",
        "facility": "Box",
        "user": "KellyAnne Conway",
        "object_type": "DiscoverOrg Debug Log",
        "File_Size": 997.20972647644385,
        "Object_Id": "13efab244409d3a384",
        "__source": "API",
        "object_name": 190852,
        "Activity_type": "Download",
        "location": "somewhere",
        "created_timestamp": "2017-07-19T23:23:52",
        "device": "thing",
        "message": "words",
        "inserted_timestamp": "2017-07-19T23:23:52",
        "user_name": "KellyAnneConway",
        "elastica_user": "KellyAnneConway",
        "browser": "ibrows"
    }
}, {
    "_type": "Log4K",
    "_id": "baf2b75f2c99808380111b",
    "_source": {
        "severity": "informational",
        "facility": "Box",
        "user": "KellyAnne Conway",
        "object_type": "DiscoverOrg Debug Log",
        "File_Size": 999.6903850242071,
        "Object_Id": "94938cc74f38959add",
        "__source": "API",
        "object_name": 366190,
        "Activity_type": "Download",
        "location": "somewhere",
        "created_timestamp": "2017-07-19T23:24:52",
        "device": "thing",
        "message": "words",
        "inserted_timestamp": "2017-07-19T23:24:52",
        "user_name": "KellyAnneConway",
        "elastica_user": "KellyAnneConway",
        "browser": "ibrows"
    }
}]
```

Now if you validate you won't get error